# problem creating Mac launcher script for wine/heidisql

Tags: macos, wine, heidisql

Ok, mac scripts are completely new to me, and I have no idea how to debug this.

I have installed wine from the pkg (not from brew etc) and installed heidisql with wine.

As per instructions, I created this in the mac script editor, saved it as "application" and copied it to Applications folder.

NOTE: I can run heidisql by running "wine stable" in the launcher, then typing in

```
wine "$HOME/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/HeidiSQL/heidisql.exe"
```

The script which doesn't work:

```
on run

    --edit this to be the correct location and file to run (typically only edit after the "drive_c")
    set toRun to "$HOME/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/HeidiSQL/heidisql.exe"

    --edit winePrefix if you are not using the default prefix
    set winePrefix to "$HOME/.wine"

    --edit wineLocation if your wine install is not the default location
    set wineLocation to "/usr/local/bin"

    --edit dyldFallbackLibraryPath to your X11 lib folder, this one is set for XQuartz on 10.6+
    set dyldFallbackLibraryPath to "/opt/X11/lib"
    -------------------------------------------------------
    --DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE
    -------------------------------------------------------
    set toRunPath to do shell script "WINEPREFIX=\"" & winePrefix & "\"; TEMPVAR=\"" & toRun & "\"; echo \"${TEMPVAR%/*}\""
    set toRunFile to do shell script "WINEPREFIX=\"" & winePrefix & "\"; TEMPVAR=\"" & toRun & "\"; TEMPVAR2=\"" & toRunPath & "\"; echo \"${TEMPVAR#$TEMPVAR2/}\""
    do shell script "PATH=\"" & wineLocation & ":$PATH\"; export WINEPREFIX=\"" & winePrefix & "\"; export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=\"" & dyldFallbackLibraryPath & "\"; cd \"" & toRunPath & "\"; wine \"" & toRunFile & "\" > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

end run
```

However, when I run the application script by double-clicking on it in the application folder, it flashes up the script icon in the taskbar, then does nothing.  Any idea what's wrong, or how to debug?

Comment: I would throw in a `display dialog(toRunPath)` after setting that variable, then same again for `toRunFile`

Comment: toRunPath = "/Users/myname/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/HeidiSQL" toRunFile = heidisql.exe, both of which are correct unfortunately.

Comment: I think I see the problem. I am using the official script from the documenation on wineHQ. I also use the package installer for win from wineHQ, without changing any defaults.  However, it looks like wine is not in /usr/local/bin, its in /Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution.  Did "which wine" to find out where the installer put it, and replaced /usr/bin/local in script.

```
on run

    --edit this to be the correct location and file to run (typically only edit after the "drive_c")
    set toRun to "$HOME/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/HeidiSQL/heidisql.exe"

    --edit winePrefix if you are not using the default prefix
    set winePrefix to "$HOME/.wine"

    --edit wineLocation if your wine install is not the default location
    --  set wineLocation to "/usr/local/bin"
    set wineLocation to "/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/"

    --edit dyldFallbackLibraryPath to your X11 lib folder, this one is set for XQuartz on 10.6+
    set dyldFallbackLibraryPath to "/opt/X11/lib"
    -------------------------------------------------------
    --DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE
    -------------------------------------------------------
    set toRunPath to do shell script "WINEPREFIX=\"" & winePrefix & "\"; TEMPVAR=\"" & toRun & "\"; echo \"${TEMPVAR%/*}\""
    set toRunFile to do shell script "WINEPREFIX=\"" & winePrefix & "\"; TEMPVAR=\"" & toRun & "\"; TEMPVAR2=\"" & toRunPath & "\"; echo \"${TEMPVAR#$TEMPVAR2/}\""


    do shell script "PATH=\"" & wineLocation & ":$PATH\"; export WINEPREFIX=\"" & winePrefix & "\"; export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=\"" & dyldFallbackLibraryPath & "\"; cd \"" & toRunPath & "\"; wine \"" & toRunFile & "\" > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

end run
```